# QGIS 3.28 - 3.32 - Can not open .LAS-file format

Tags: qgis, lidar, las

I have multiple datasets of LAS-files, which I can not open in QGIS. I get an error stating LAYER is not supported or something like that.

I do, however, have files with an .ept extension in JSON-format. I don't know where these come from. If I open these, it works.

My goal is to create VPC of all my LAS-files. I'm trying to open my LAS-files with

1. Just adding the LAS-file to the layer manager
2. Opening the LAS-file with Build VPC
3. Opening the LAS-file with Create COPC

Non of these works.